# Tank Dents - 69 Yamaha L5T

Tags: motorcycle, fuel-tank, yamaha, dent

I've been trying to get a larger dent out of my old gas tank for a while now and am having no luck. I've been trying the hot glue method and am having no luck. This tank seems to be too thick for this method to work.

I went to a dent specialist and was told $300 so I ran from that deal. Does anyone have any tips or ways they have fixed a tank?

Let me know your ideas / tips or if I should give up and just let it add character to the bike.

Lastly, from Minneapolis/Saint Paul if anyone knows a guy.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found a video with 4 methods to fix dents on motorcycle gas tanks. The hot glue method was mentioned in this video.

The person in the video uses a hair drier and a can of compressed air for the first method.

The tank that he is working on has a single wall in the gas tank.

The 4th method is pretty interesting and it seems to be the most successful method for the Kawasaki tank he is working on.

The guy takes a blood pressure gauge he got off of Ebay and jams it in the hole of the tank. He pumps the gauge and it causes the dent to expand.

All credit goes to the creator of the video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qkbFhPrJ14w

Comment: With a dent that large, you should just buy a new tank, or get it professionally repaired. Using air to pop out a dent like that will also pop out any other features the tank has. Let's say, dimples to hold it onto the frame.